# Retrieve models that belongsToMany specific models

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I've got a standard many-to-many relationship

```
class User {
  public function roles() {
    return $this->belongsToMany('Role');
  }
}

class Role {
  public function users() {
    return $this->belongsToMany('User');
  }
}
```

And it works very well.

But I need to select all the users that has exactly two specific roles.

```
$roleAdmin = Role::where('name', 'admin')->first();
$roleUser = Role::where('name', 'user')->first();

$users = //which users has BOTH $roleAdmin and $roleUser ??
```

Is it possible to achieve this using eloquent or I need a raw query?

PS the use-case is stupid, I know, it's just an abstraction of my real problem (that doesn't concern users and roles)

Answer (score 1):

The best solution I found is to get admins and users and then use [`intersect()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/collections#method-intersect) helper to get only users who are present both in `$users` and `admins` collections:

```
$users = User::whereHas('roles', function ($q) use($otherRoles) {
            $q->where('name', 'user')->whereNotIn('name', $otherRoles);
         })->get();

$admins = User::whereHas('roles', function ($q) use($otherRoles) {
            $q->where('name', 'admin')->whereNotIn('name', $otherRoles);
         })->get();

$result = $admins->intersect($users);
```

If you want to save some memory, you could `pluck()` only IDs, `intersect()` these and only then get users with `whereIn()`.

Comment: It won't work. It returns also users that have only a role (whereIn is similar to an OR clause) I need user that are both users and admin.

Comment: It not works as expected. If an user has 3 roles ('user', 'admin, 'superadmin') it should be filtered out.

Comment: @alberto-bottarini I've updated my answer. You need to pass an array of all other roles `$otherRoles = ['superadmin', 'guest', 'moderator']`

Answer (score 0):

This is not an eloquent solution(by all means)

```
$users = \DB::table('users')
        ->select(\DB::raw("GROUP_CONCAT(roles.name SEPARATOR '-') as `role_names`"), 'users.name')
        ->join('role_user', 'users.id', '=', 'role_user.user_id')
        ->join('roles', 'roles.id', '=', 'role_user.role_id')
        ->groupBy('users.id')
        ->having('role_names', '=', 'admin-user')
        ->get();
```

`admin-user` can be `user-admin`, which roles names comes first in the database. Please change `table` and `column` names as per your requirement

Comment: It should work. Maybe introducing a sort mechanism that force role to be alphabetically sorted.

Comment: yeah, I know its not the most elegant way, but should do the work.